# how to prohibit multiple execution using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to know how to prohibit multiple execution using pyinstaller

the command I use to have the exe is

```
pyinstaller -w -F --hidden-import "babel.numbers" --icon=images/look.ico App.py
```

Know this works fine but when executing multiple times many instance of the same application will start at the same time.

I want to have one instance of the application even run the exe multiple times

Comment: As far as I understood your problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2483). They suggest to remove the -F command to run the .exe only in one instance. I don't know if it works with multiple execution.

Comment: @Maeaex1 this didn't help even after removing -F

Comment: `-F` is just a flag how the application is built. This has no influence on running multiple instances (or not).